# How do I create an eclipse Run Configuration that applies to all script files that match a pattern?

Tags: eclipse, perl, run-configuration, epic

I am using eclipse with Perl EPIC for Perl scripting. It appears I have to create an individual Run Configuration for each script file I want to run, which seems overkill:
[image]

Is there a way to create a Run Configuration that is always applied to script files that match a filename pattern?

I don't want to have to keep creating Run Configurations for every individual script.

Alternatively, is there a way to automagically add a new Run Configuration to the list upon first run of said script if I choose, say e.g., "Run As -> Perl Local"?